# Hotmail CheckAvailability Api

Tags: hotmail

hi i have a little problem here.
i searched on google for this but nothing gud is available.
i had a application with more than 2000 ids.
i just want to find out whether those ids are registered in Hotmail or not. If possible i want to use the Hotmail api to check the availability of the id in hotmail.

Thanks

Comment: What is the scenario? Is it something like where you need to validate if your user is registering with a valid email id?

Comment: yes. i just want to check whether the email id is already registered in Hotmail or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail (or any other email provider) will not give you this facility, because it will open the main doors for spammers. They can validate the id and then enjoy.